# plot data from pandas DataFrame, colour dependent on column value

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have tried multiple codes to condition the bar plot colour to a particular value. It seems that the color function only checks for the first item in the index (in this case Germany) and sets the condition for all other items in the index. I would really appreciate if anybody could help:

```
colors = ['red' if 'Germany' else 'lightgrey' for x in first5_countries.index] #it colors all bars red
colors = ['r' if 'IT' else 'b' for index in first5_countries.index] #it colors everything red
colors = ['r' if pop_mln>85 else 'b' for pop_mln in first5_countries.pop_mln] #all bars blue
colors = ['r' if index=='Italy' else 'b' for index in first5_countries.index] #all bars blue
colors = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'r', 'b'] #yields blue
```

The whole code:

```
sorted_df = population_2019.sort_values(by='pop_mln', ascending=False)
first5_countries = sorted_df[:5]
colors = ['r' if index=='Italy' else 'b' for index in first5_countries.index]
first5_countries[['pop_mln']].plot.bar(figsize=(20,5), legend=False, color=colors)
plt.ylabel('Total population (in million)', size=12)
plt.xticks(rotation=30, ha='right')
plt.xlabel('')
plt.grid(axis='y')
plt.show()
```

Printout of first5_countries:

```
    geo sex age year    total_pop   pop_mln
geo_full                        
Germany DE  T   TOTAL   2019    83019213.0  83.019213
France  FR  T   TOTAL   2019    67012883.0  67.012883
United Kingdom  UK  T   TOTAL   2019    66647112.0  66.647112
Italy   IT  T   TOTAL   2019    60359546.0  60.359546
Spain   ES  T   TOTAL   2019    46937060.0  46.937060
```

[population](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7xBr.jpg)

```
first5_countries.index.values
```

array(['Germany', 'France', 'United Kingdom', 'Italy', 'Spain'],
dtype=object)

Comment: Try `color = ['lightgrey', 'lightgrey', 'lightgrey', 'red', 'lightgrey']`. Or just create a color variable list before.

Comment: @SergeyDyshko I tried this method but it also does not work - I assigned the first column with country names as an index and it does not seem to be picked up when called out :(

Answer (score 1):

You can define your `colors` like this:

```
colors = ['red' if x=='Italy' else 'lightgray' for x in first5_countries.index]
```

And then pass to the plot function:

```
first5_countries['population_mln'].plot.bar(figsize=(20,5),color=colors, legend=False)
```

Together, you would do:

```
colors = ['red' if x=='Italy' else 'lightgray' for x in first5_countries.index]

first5_countries['pop_mln'].plot.bar(figsize=(20,5),color=colors, legend=False)
```

Output would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: That's useful, thank you but the function does not seem to pick up the country name Italy (nor any other). The function does something weird, eg. colors = ['red' if x=='Germany' else 'yellow' for x in first5_countries.index] returns every bar in red while colors = ['lightgrey' if x=='Italy' else 'yellow' for x in first5_countries.index] returns everything in yellow

Comment: Replace `first5_countries.index` with `first5_countries['country_col']` where `country_col` is the name of your country column.

Comment: Unfortunately the column name 'geo_full' is not recognised, I previously set that column as an index column with demo_pjangroup = demo_pjangroup.set_index('geo_full') - the column includes all country names

Comment: It also does not work with any other condition, eg. colors = ['lightgrey' if x>60 else 'red' for x in first5_countries['population_mln']]

Comment: @Magdalena can you update your post with a printout of `first5_countries`?

Comment: @Magdalena code works fine with the provided sample data.

Comment: I updated the thread above, tried multiple codes but none yields the result. Would appreciate further help on why this is the case.